# Matlab find zero value with certain range

Tags: matlab, matrix, find

I have this matrix:

```
A =[22    22   142   142   142    92    92    92     0     0
     0   109   109   151   151   151    23    23   149   149
     0     0     0   152   152   152    38    38     0     0
     0    13    13   113   113   113   119   119   119     0
     0     8     8     8    84    84    14    14    14     0
     0     0   144   144   144     0     0     0    66    66
    139   139   139   34    34    34     0     0     0     0
     0     0    64    64    64   128   128    59    59    59
    83    83    83    65    65    65    67    67    67     0];
```

How can I find indices (row, column) from matrix with zero value respectively 2 or more?

Comment: What does "respectively 2 or more" mean? What is the desired output for your example? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`find`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) as follows:

```
[r,c] = find(A==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[rows,cols] = ind2sub(size(A),find(A==0))
```

`find` gives you the indices and `ind2sub` converts them in column-row format.